# Why do some devices ship without the Market installed?

Tags: google-play-store, coby-kyros

Someone explain to me why some tablet manufacturers use software hubs other than **Market**.
I bought a **Coby Kyros** ($160 @ KMart, Puerto Rico) and it brings **AppsLib** instead, and I immediately noticed that not all apps are there.
I already found steps to root the tablet and install Market, but the question still bugs me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Google only allows the Market, which is not open-source like the rest of Android, to be bundled with devices that passes their [Compatibility Test Suite](http://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-intro.html).  Devices that do not pass are not "officially" Android devices.

Comment: Actually, it also seems like they simply don't allow it for devices with only WiFi. I guess one reason could be that they at least used to use the sim card ID to figure out if you lived in a country where the payware part of market should be enabled and a few other things.

Comment: "Android 2.3 MAY be used on devices that do not include telephony hardware. That is, Android 2.3 is compatible with devices that are not phones." http://source.android.com/compatibility/android-2.3-cdd.pdf

Comment: Yes it may, but as I understand it this was about Market and not about Android. Google, to my knowledge, still don't allow Market on devices lacking telephony hardware. Most of the vendors of such devices have their own Market (or people download the Market apk from elsewhere).

Comment: No, all "approved" Android devices can use the Market. The WiFi-only version of the Samsung Galaxy Tab has the Market, for example.

Comment: Ok, I read it the other day but it looks like most wifi only Honeycomb tablets include Market so it has either changed or wasn't entirely true.