# I have a Binatone Kidzstar and can't install android market or google play

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some devices ship without the Market installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4122/why-do-some-devices-ship-without-the-market-installed)
>   [How can I add the market to my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/how-can-i-add-the-market-to-my-device)

I have a Binatone Kidzstar and can't install android market or google play.  i can't understand why not as its running 4.0 ice cream sandwich, why would i not have access????

Comment: Probably the manufacter didn't want to put Play Store for some reason. Have you tried to install it by APK?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add the market to my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/how-can-i-add-the-market-to-my-device) -- another source: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Android itself, Google Play Market (and the rest of Google Apps) is a proprietary software, it is only available for tablets that passes the compatibility test suite. Additionally, even for devices that passes the test suite, it's up to the device manufacturer whether they want to include any parts of the Google Apps; some manufacturers have various reasons for not including the Play Store.

Comment: so where can i download apps from? i'm new to android, i bought this because my kids love playing on my ipad.  This seamed to have a kiddie front end on top of a android tablet so its not just a expensive kids toy.  But if i can't install apps i can't see the point of it. android opperating system just to run the browser????

Comment: @rob see http://android.stackexchange.com/q/216/1465